# Logging levels in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

Could someone explain me what is the difference between setting `logging.level.*=LEVEL`, `logging.level.=LEVEL` and `logging.level.root=LEVEL` in `application.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This: `logging.level.root=LEVEL` sets the log level for the root logger. It is the equivalent of this configuration taken from a `logback.xml`:

```
<root level="...">
    ...
</root>
```

These: `logging.level.*=LEVEL`, `logging.level.=LEVEL` are used to set the log level for specific loggers. For example:

- `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`
- `logging.level.com.x.y=ERROR`

The log level assigned to the root logger is, implicitly, applied to all individual logger instances unless you have configured specific loggers with their own levels. So, these `logging.level.*=LEVEL`, `logging.level.=LEVEL` allow you to override the root logger's level for specific, named, logger instances.